Managing Contents Across Contentful - Multiple Domains + Locales
We have a huge codebase, and I ll make it simple here.
I have a Header Component, A Body Component, and a Footer Component and we have three domains, EN, PT and DE.
If I am in UK Domain, I have options to view the Website only in English.
If I am in PT Domain, I have options to view the Website in Two English and Portuguese.
If I am in DE Domain, I have options to view the Website in Two German and German.
Now,
The Header Component if I am in UK Domain should say, Hello, Welcome to Skynet.
The Header Component if I am in DE Domain should say,
Hallo, Guten Tag. when in German and Hello, Good Day when in English
The Header Component if I am in PT Domain should say,
Hallo, Bom Dia. when in PT and Hello, Have a nice day when switched to English.
Currently the Contentful Configuration goes as,
{
    header: Short Text, // Localization Enable
    content: Rich Text, // Localization Enable
    footer: JSON // Localization Enable
    domainSpecific: JSON
}

And we have the Contents as,
  header : "Hello, Welcome to Skynet",
  header : "{domainSpecificHeader}",
  header : "{domainSpecificHeader}"
  domainSpecific: 
  { PT: "Good Day", DE:"Hello, Have a nice Day"  }

The variable {domainSpecificHeader} is been replaced with domainSpecific.PT and domainSpecific.DE whenever needed.
This goes tedious, as we have more than 100 plus models, and each Domains English version doesnt align with UK's English version.
And in Contentful, I could just use these two fields

Is there any better way to configure
For a fallback, using JSON for Domain Specific and replacing it in the code base, but there are similar content models, and more contents and too many replaces in the codebase which doesnt look neat
